# How to access the new variables value in same Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I'm learning the loop feature to set a dictionary variable from another variable in the same playbook like below:

```yaml
vars:
- name: original var users contain multiple user's elements
  users:
    - name: alice
      authorized:
        - /tmp/alice/onekey.pub
        - /tmp/alice/twokey.pub
      mysql:
        password: "mysql-Alice's password"
        hosts:
          - "%"
          - "127.0.0.1"
          - "::1"
          - "localhost"
```

Then in a task, I get the needed key/value from the variable above to set a new dictionary variable `mysql_user` like below:

```yaml
- name: combine all elements data into one variable - MySQL users
  mysql_user: "name={{ item.0.user }} password={{ item.0.mysql.password }} host={{ item.1 }} priv={{ item.0.mysql.privs | join('/') }}"
  loop: "{{users|subelements('mysql.hosts')}}"
  #with_subelements:
  #  - users
  #  - mysql.hosts
```

And you can see I tried the old `with_subelements` and new the `loop` construct, but both begets same error when the below task runs:

```yaml
- name: display varible's value - combined varibles
  debug:
    msg: |
      "{{ mysql_user }}"
```

Error:

> fatal: [s1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: name={{ item.0.user }} password={{ item.0.mysql.password }}

It obviously complains that the new varible `mysql_user` does not exist, so, my question actually is how to get the new variable or say it as a internal dictionary key/value in same playbook?

Comment: You're playing with fire using that legacy `key=value` syntax for `mysql_user:`; at the very least reproduce this problem using the sane yaml syntax and then you're more likely to get help, versus trying to decipher how ansible interprets a string of whitespace delimited ini values into structured data

Comment: You seem to confuse var declaration and tasks. Vars section should be a simple dict, not a list with elements having a name.

Comment: Hi Zeitounator, my purpose is to use a task to gain a new var with value generated from dynamic value combined from existed vars.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see you are setting the variable mysql_user. Maybe your code should have looked more like

```
- name: combine all elements data into one variable - MySQL users
  set_fact:
      mysql_user: "name={{ item.0.user }} password={{ item.0.mysql.password }} host={{ item.1 }} priv={{ item.0.mysql.privs | join('/') }}"
  loop: "{{users|subelements('mysql.hosts')}}"
```

At least the last value should be retained.

But if you register the command output all the loop iterations' output is collected in a list - the registered variable will be a list with one entry for each loop invocation. Just make sure the necessary data is printed by the loop content.

```
- name: combine all elements data into one variable - MySQL users
  debug:
      msg: "name={{ item.0.user }} password={{ item.0.mysql.password }} host={{ item.1 }} priv={{ item.0.mysql.privs | join('/') }}"
  loop: "{{users|subelements('mysql.hosts')}}"
  register: mysql_user

- name: print the obtained values
  debug:
    var: mysql_user
```

Comment: thanks, this works somehow, and as you pointed out it only hold the last value from the loop. any further guildance?

Comment: Thanks Hiran, your answer works.  I noticed the register var used.